# Hibernate MySQL UTF8 Lookup Issue with Foreign Characters

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, collation

I have a simple spring/hibernate app which is backed by a MySQL DB.

The DB is character set `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4_bin`. I have a lot of data that contains non-latin characters.

I have a table of pages (id, pagename, text) where pagename is a unique index and I query this table using the Hibernate Criteria API:

```
Page result = session.createQuery(query.where(
                builder.equal(root.get("pagename"), name)
        ).select(root)).getSingleResult();
```

For some values, I have a `ResultNotFound` exception. Despite there being a record that matches. I can verify this by querying:

```
select count(*) from page where pagename="Tři_oříšky_pro_Popelku"
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If I compare the string in Java though looking up by the PK instead of this UK, the string comparison returns `true`

```
session.createSQLQuery(
    "select * from page p where p.id = :pid")
    .addEntity(Page.class)
    .setParameter("pid", 29752).list().get(0).getPageName().equals(name);
```

Am I missing something really simple here? I've tried playing with character set and encodings in the hibernate config file and am pretty stuck!

I'm using `org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.2.10.Final` and `mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6`

Comment: What's your connection string? You should specify the charset there

Comment: I'd set it in the hibernate config:         <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>

Comment: Did you try append useUnicode and characterEncoding to connection.url property? I always set that in my previous project..

Comment: well. apparently that worked... :sigh:

Comment: Jacob, I added ?characterEncoding=utf-8 and that fixed it. Thanks for spotting it. I thought that you'd only have to do one, not both.